# Create SP Online list item using email data

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, email, list-item

I want to create SharePoint list item using email data sent to me? I get service requests through email in a specific template. Emails contents will be like below:

```
Name:         George Thomas
Email:        Georgethomas@email.com
Start Date:   1/22/2018
End Date:     1/25/2018
Issue:        Issue Description
Location:     North America,Asia
```

What are the ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Get the users to email their service requests to a Sharepoint List.  You can manage all user issues from there.

You can use views to set up a user view of issues so that it only filters on their own issues too, if you so wish.

Go in List Settings>Incoming Email Settings

[image: Enable email]

OR

Create a Service Request List and allow users to create new items.  In the List Settings, restrict users so they can only view/edit their own items.

- Set all fields to 'required', to ensure you get all the info you need.
- Add some Choice fields (you can define some categories this way).
- Every time a new item is added it automatically has a Sharepoint List ID assigned to it, that can be your SR number.
- All users would need is a link to the SR List; add it to your intranet, they can add it to their browser favourites (or you just email them the link).

Comment: But Incoming Email uploads the email as a file to document library right?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it's not as easy as I anticipated.  I've not done it myself before, but I found a couple of links on it, but it would involve using an events receiver.  [Link1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/72df2dc5-906e-437c-b6a4-23a199d4e387/email-integration-and-populating-custom-list-columns?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)  [Link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fa231713-7618-43b6-ab27-3b55e39f487b/enable-incoming-emails-for-sharepoint-2013-lists-can-i-control-the-permission-and-the-mapped?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: I want the email data to be updated into SP list columns automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: that would be best, I agree.  I've not done this before though.  You could look in to making a Word template with Quick Part fields (fields from Sharepoint) embedded in to it.  Or better still, you could just not bother with the email - just get users to go to your Service Request list and use +add new item.  They simply add a new item to the List.  You can configure the list so they can't see or edit other people's items.  This might be the best option coming to think of it.